# Is accessing two AtomicIntegers as one operation thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

In Brian Goetz's *Java Concurrency in Practice,* there is an example as follows:

```
public class NumberRange {
  // INVARIANT: lower <= upper
  private final AtomicInteger lower = new AtomicInteger(0);
  private final AtomicInteger upper = new AtomicInteger(0);

  public void setLower(int i) {
    // Warning -- unsafe check-then-act
    if (i > upper.get())
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
    "can't set lower to " + i + " > upper");
    lower.set(i);
  }

  public void setUpper(int i) {
    // Warning -- unsafe check-then-act
    if (i < lower.get())
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
      "can't set upper to " + i + " < lower");
    upper.set(i);
  }

  public boolean isInRange(int i) {
    return (i >= lower.get() && i <= upper.get());
  }
}
```

I understand that the above code is prone to race conditions.

Then he explains following:

> Multivariable invariants like this one create atomicity requirements: related variables must be fetched or updated in a single atomic operation. You cannot update one, release and reacquire the lock, and then update the others, since this could involve leaving the object in an invalid state when the lock was released.

Of what i understand from this paragraph is that if we make the `setUpper` and the `setLower` functions `synchronized`, then also there will be situations when the object might reach an invalid state. However, I think that if both functions are synchronized then only one thread can execute either of the function and each function has necessary checks for the invariant. How can we be left in invalid state. Can anyone demonstrate with an example. What am i missing here?

If i am understanding it correctly, then what is the significance of this line:

> You cannot update one, release and reacquire the lock, and then update the others, since this could involve leaving the object in an invalid state when the lock was released.

Comment: I don't see any problem if they're synchronized. There's just no point in using `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: Without spending a lot of time running different tests, it's possible that between the check of `i` and the setting of `i`, the value of `lower` or `upper` can be changed by a different thread, making the check invalid.  The point is, between the `get` and the `set`, you need to prevent any other threads from modifying the state of the value

Comment: @MadProgrammer I know that can happen. But what is the author trying to explain in the paragraph i mentioned.

Comment: @JotWaraich Pretty much what I said.  `get` guarantees the value at the time the method returns, but, between it and the `set`, that state can change, you can not guarantee the state is the same when `set` is called from when `get` was called.  You need to generate an atomic state, when you can reason that when `set` is called, the state has not been modified since `get` was called.  If `get` and `set` are called within the context of the same lock, then it should be safe to continue

Comment: If the methods are made synchronized, then will it still be prone to race conditions? Also what is the significance of the line i mentioned in the bottom of the question then?

Comment: @JotWaraich I think what you're missing is that the line that you're highlighting refers to the higher level of granularity of locking used in the example (using `AtomicInteger`s), not the less granular version in which we're locking on `this` (instance methods that include `synchronized` lock on `this`).

Comment: I don't think he's addressing this particular snippet. His point is that it's not enough to protect each field individually when you have multivariable invariants.

Comment: Do `AtomicInteger` have any kind of locking? @JanusVarmarken

Comment: I am still not able to understand what the author wants to say.

Comment: @JotWaraich Sorry, my choice of words was perhaps a bit hasty as `AtomicInteger` (if I recall correctly) is implemented using CAS, not mutexes. Nevertheless, my point about granularity still stands, regardless of the implementation :).

Comment: Sorry about this, I misread the example.  See Bohemian's comments below.  Synchronized doesn't work because `setUpper` and `setLower` are two separate operations, and they need to be made atomic together or it's possible for two threads to interleave and violate a constraint.

Comment: @markspace can you please formulate an answer of all what you are saying....it will be more easy then...thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the **"Java Concurrency in Practice"** book:

> NumberRange could be made thread-safe by using locking to maintain its
>   invariants, such as guarding lower and upper with a common lock. It
>   must also avoid publishing lower and upper to prevent clients from
>   subverting its invariants.

That means the following code is thread-safe:

```
@ThreadSafe
public class NumberRange {

    @GuardedBy("this") private int lower, upper;

    public synchronized void setLower(int i) {
        if (i > upper) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("can't set lower to " + i + " > upper");
        }
        lower = i;
    }

    public synchronized void setUpper(int i) {
        if (i < lower) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("can't set upper to " + i + " < lower");
        }
        upper = i;
    }

    public synchronized boolean isInRange(int i) {
        return (i >= lower && i <= upper);
    }
}
```

In this case, the `NumberRange` provides its own locking to ensure that compound actions are atomic.

Comment: I interpreted it the same way. But @Oleksandr one thing which is creating a doubt in my mind is this line : You cannot update one, release and reacquire the lock, and then update the others, since this could involve leaving the object in an invalid state when the lock was released

Comment: This snippet is not safe. Example to break it:

setup: x.setLower(0); x.setUpper(100);
thread 1: x.setLower(80);
thread 2: x.setUpper(50);

With the right interleave you end up with a lower of 80 and an upper of 50 which breaks the invariants.

Comment: It’s not safe, because setting the range is not atomic. You need a `setRange(int, int)` method.

Comment: @Bohemian I don't agree with you. Take a look at the similar example in the book: `paragraph 4.3.5`, `listing 4.11`.

Comment: I don’t care what it says. It’s wrong. Just like Vector was thought to be threadsafe, but it isn’t really.

Comment: @Bohemian please explain it in detail with an answer...i will be thankful

Comment: @JotWaraich 1) range has state 5..7 and thread 1 wants to change range to 1..3 and thread 2 wants 11..13, 2) thread 1 call setLower(1) - state = 1..7 already a problem, 3) thread 2 calls setLower(11) - state = 11..7 which is meaningless, 4) thread 2 calls setUpper(13) - state = 11..13, 5) thread 1 calls setUpper(3). Final state = 11..3 oops! See how you just make the change in state an atomic action - ie set all state in one synced method. Synchronised methods **does not** mean threadsafe!!!

Comment: @Bohemian i am starting to get what you are saying. Little more clarification. How is state 1..7 already a problem? How can we achieve state 11..7, i think it will throw an exception. Also similarly 11..3 will lead to an exception?

Comment: @Bohemian I think you misunderstood the main point of these tiny examples in the book and in my answer. It's not about setting the range, it's about setting one particular variable - `lower` or `upper` (check `lower`, update `upper`, and vice versa - a compound operation). Also, your example will produce an `Exception`, you can't setup an invalid range. You didn't even test the code...

Comment: @Bohemian, Oleksandr is right. The invariant we're trying to protect is `lower <= upper`, and this does a perfectly good job at that.